# how do i get rid of the bugs (what is wrong with my script )

Tags: android, bash

i have written a bash script that uses nice, renice and oom priority(optional ), to bulletproof apps periodically, it check for the app if running renices it else, nices it for the next time running, but there are bugs and because I am new to bash scripting I needed some help, this is for a sony ericsson xperia x10 running gingerbread, but other than the app names, all the commands are standard busybox commands

```
#!/system/bin/sh
#prioritizer script version 2
while true
do
    phoneid='pidof com.android.phone';
    if[ $phoneid ]
    then
    renice -17 $phoneid ;
        #/system/xbin/echo "-17" > /proc/$phoneid/oom_adj;

    else
        nice --17 'com.android.phone' ;

    fi
    hid='pidof com.sonyericsson.home';
    if[ $hid ]
    then
        renice -18 $hid ;
        #/system/xbin/echo "-18" > /proc/$hid/oom_adj;

    else
        nice --17 'com.sonyericsson.home' ;
    fi
    supid='pidof com.noshufou.android.su';
    if[ $supid ]
    then
        renice -17 $supid ;
        #/system/xbin/echo "-17" > /proc/$supid/oom_adj;
    else
        nice --17 'com.noshufou.android.su';
    fi
    renice -17  'pidof com.android.mms'
    renice -14 'pidof com.sonyericsson.music'
    renice -17 'pidof android.process.media'
    renice -16 'pidof mediaserver'
    renice 5 'pidof com.google.process.gapps'
    renice 5 'pidof com.Google.android.apps.uploader '
    sleep 1000

done
exit 0
```

if you can find the error or show me a good scripting guide i will be thankful

Comment: The code is a lot easier to read with proper indentation.  I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In a shell there is no such statement as <strike>`if[`</strike>. You need a space after each `if`.

Also, after:

```
phoneid='pidof com.android.phone'
```

you have in your variable text: "*pidof com.android.phone*" instead of output of that command. You need to use `` `command param ...` `` or (preferably) `$(command param ...)` syntax.

Remember to check you shell syntax with:

```
/bin/sh -n myscript.sh
```

The command above (run on your PC) will not try to run the script, just check the syntax.

Also, You have a lot of uneeded semicolons, but this will not fail your script.